# Detox "Cannot read property 'bindings' of null" error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, testing, detox

I tried adding Detox e2e testing to my react native app and I am running into the following error when trying to run a simple test.

[image]

I have only installed Detox to the iOS side of the app. The "detox build" command executed perfectly.

Below are the important files from my project.

Package.json

```
{
 "name": "ExerFit_mobileapp",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
   "test": "jest"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "bcrypt": "^3.0.7",
   "firebase": "^5.5.9",
   "moment": "^2.24.0",
   "native-base": "^2.13.8",
   "qs": "^6.9.0",
   "react": "16.3.1",
   "react-native": "0.55.4",
   "react-native-custom-tabs": "^0.1.7",
   "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
   "react-native-navigation": "^3.7.0",
   "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
   "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
   "rn-apple-healthkit": "^0.6.5",
   "switch-button-react-native": "^1.0.3"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
   "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
   "detox": "^15.1.4",
   "jest": "24.9.0",
   "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
 },
 "jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
 },
 "detox": {
   "test-runner": "jest",
   "specs": "e2e",
   "configurations": {
     "ios.sim.debug": {
       "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExerFit_mobileapp.app",
    "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/ExerFit_mobileapp.xcworkspace -scheme ExerFit_mobileapp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "name": "iPhone 7"
  }
}
}
}
```

config.json

```
{
"setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./init.js"],
"testEnvironment": "node",
"reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
"verbose": true
}
```

init.js

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');
const specReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/specReporter');


jest.setTimeout(120000);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(config);
}, 300000);

beforeEach(async () => {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

Comment: What does your `.babelrc` look like?

Comment: {
      "presets": ["react-native"]
    }